# RPM install error: Failed dependencies: /bin/sh is needed by<rpmname>

Tags: rpm

1. I am getting following error while installing RPM. error: Failed dependencies: /bin/sh is needed by rpm name
2. Command "rpm -ivh rpm file path"
3. When I use "rpm -ivh rpm file path --nodeps". It is working fine. But I don't want to use --nodeps option each time.

Any way to get out .. Thanks in advance.

Comment: on which OS are you installing; such that /bin/sh is not present?

Comment: I am using CentOS release 6.5 (Final). 
/bin/sh is present on the same.

Comment: then it is a mystery to me... you can investigate the dependencies of the rpm using `rpm -qp <file path> --requires`

Comment: Above command giving me output as
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1

Comment: normally that shouldn't be a problem since /bin/sh is installed... very strange. Sorry no real idea how to work around that

Comment: I'm going to guess you have a shell script in the RPM that has DOS line endings, and it is *really* requiring `/bin/sh<CR><LF>` or something similar, which you do not have. Try running `xxd file.sh | head` on all your scripts and ensure it is just `0x0A` at the end of the line.

Comment: It looks like /var/lib/rpm/ folder is not present on my machine. Tell me how to reinstall rpm again.

Answer (score -3):

Disable automatic detection of dependencies. Add the following to your spec file.

AutoReqProv: no

Comment: I stand corrected. This option is primarily designed for shared libraries.